# game: square doesnt fall in canvas fiddle javascript, html5

Tags: javascript

I'm creating this jumping game

**PROBLEM**

Withing the jumping logic I add `Player.y +=Player.vy;` to make the red square fall once reached the higher level (simulating gravity), but it just get stucked at the top. https://jsfiddle.net/0f34at75/6/

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var ground = 130;
var Player = {
    x: 20,
    y: ground,
    vx: 5,
    vy: 5,
    yMax: 10,
    gravity: 3,
    jumping: false
};

function jump() {
    Player.jumping = true;

}

function gravity() {

    if (Player.jumping == true) {
        if (Player.y < Player.yMax) {
            Player.y += Player.vy;
        } else {
            Player.y -= Player.vy;
        }


    } else {

        Player.y = ground;
    }

}



function createPlayer() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(Player.x, Player.y, 50, 50);
}

function createGround() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 180, 100, 50);
}


function ClearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}


setInterval(function() {
    ClearCanvas();
    gravity();
    createGround()
    createPlayer();
}, 20);

canvas.addEventListener("click", jump);
```

```css
#myCanvas{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200">click</canvas>
```

Comment: you need to turn off the jumping logic

Comment: if I turn it off, how do I jump if wanting to jump again

Comment: As soon as your character falls a little, your logic tells it to go back up because it's still jumping. Keep separate logic for checking if it's jumping and if it's in mid-air, turn jumping off when it's at max height but keep checking if it's in mid-air to let him fall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Nicolás Marzano says, separate your jumping and falling logic.

Alternatively (although the effect is slightly different) you might consider an actual gravity-style acceleration towards the ground, instead - the jump will look more realistic and it can be easier to programme.

```
var Player = {
  x: 20,
  y: ground,
  jumpSpeed: 5,
  vx: 0,
  vy: 0,
  gravity: 0.1
};

function jump() {
  Player.vy = -Player.jumpSpeed;
}

function gravity() {
  Player.y += Player.vy;
  Player.vy += Player.gravity;
  if (Player.y >= ground) {
     Player.y = ground;
     Player.vy = 0;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjcmrn/f1bw9nx1/10/

Comment: awesome, no need to use booleans, this is pro!! thank you +1